# Не могу подключить 1С к MySQL с помощью ODBC

Tags: mysql, 1с, odbc

Для курсача надо подключить 1с предприятие к mysql базе данных. Запилил с MySQL БД, установил 64хбитный ODBC с драйвером MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver. В управлении ODBC без каких-либо проблем подключился к своей БД. Потом отправился в 1С предприятие версии 8.3.13.1690 х64. Там в конфигураторе через "внешние источники данных" пытаюсь подключить свою базу. Однако по кд приходит ошибка:
"Источник данных не найден и не указан драйвер, используемый по умолчанию". Строка подключения выглядит так: 

`DRIVER={MySQL ODBC ANSI 8.0 Driver}; 
SERVER=localhost;(так же пробовал ;;1; и ..1. - так у меня выглядит адрес локалхоста из-за экспериментов с доменом. )
DATABASE=Study;`

Так же пытался использовать конструктор строки соединения для того же драйвера, но получил ошибку "Ошибка получения параметров строки соединения. Возможно, драйвер не позволяет получать параметры строки подключения".

Несмотря на то, что формулировки ошибок выглядят понятными. никакие эксперименты с настройками ни к чему не привели, попытки гуглить показали лишь что ошибка частая, но решается это просто отказом от ODBC в большинстве случаев. Прошу подсказать, в чём может быть проблема, или порекомендовать оптимальный альтернативный способ решения.

Comment: Код для подключения будет полностью идентичен коду на Visual Basic (можно перенести код прямо в 1С) Единственный момент который надо учесть - это разрядность ! Разрядность (х64) 1С должна совпадать с разрядностью odbc драйвера (для успешного создания COM объекта).

Answer (score 0):

```
СтрокаСоединения = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver};Server=" +
                        Соединение.Server + ";Port=" + СокрЛП(Соединение.Port) +
                        ";Database=" + СокрЛП(Соединение.DB) +
                        ";User=" + Соединение.User + ";Password=" + Соединение.Pass +
                        ";Option=3;";
```